# Replacing multiple words in string from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, replace

There's a dictionary of abbreviations, the key being the abbreviation and the value being its definition ("TTYL","Talk To You Later"). When user inputs something with more than 1 abbreviation , I want a program to replace the abbreviations with the definition as an addition to the original input. I got the program to work, but only for 1 abbreviation. I want it to be able to handle more than 1 abbreviation in a string. I believe the solution has something to do with the nested for loop, however I'm uncertain and need some help.

**Python Code:**

```
abbreviationsDictionary = {
    "ADBA":"As Directed By Arborist",
    "CRTS":"Crown Reduced To Shape",
    "NWIC":"Noob Will Improve Company"
    }

note = input("Enter note: ")
listOfWordsInNote = note.split()

updatedNote = ""
for key in abbreviationsDictionary:
    for word in listOfWordsInNote:
        if (key==word):
            updatedNote = note.replace(key,abbreviationsDictionary[key])

print(updatedNote)
```

**Current Output (only works for 1 abbreviation):**

```
Enter note: mike is going to do whatever ADBA because he knows NWIC
mike is going to do whatever ADBA because he knows Noob Will Improve Company
```

**Desired Output**

```
Enter note: mike is going to do whatever ADBA because he knows NWIC
mike is going to do whatever As Directed By Arborist because he knows Noob Will Improve Company
```

Comment: Each time you call replace, you start from `note` again, instead of starting from the updated note.

Comment: Perfect. That helped me with the solution. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you use

```
updatedNote = note.replace(key,abbreviationsDictionary[key])
```

So, each time a new key is found, you restart with note (which has not changed )

just replace by :

```
            note = note.replace(key,abbreviationsDictionary[key])
```

and print (note) :
*mike is going to do whatever As Directed By Arborist because he knows Noob Will Improve Company*

Answer (score 0):

Rather than replacing in the input string, get the [whitespace delimited] tokens from the user input then use a simple generator to reconstruct:

```
abbreviationsDictionary = {
    "ADBA": "As Directed By Arborist",
    "CRTS": "Crown Reduced To Shape",
    "NWIC": "Noob Will Improve Company"
}

note = input("Enter note: ")

print(' '.join(abbreviationsDictionary.get(loin, loin) for loin in note.split()))
```